# Storyboard Constraints : Replace views; Adjust Scroll View Height - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout, storyboard

I have created the following layout via storyboard. It consists of a scroll view whose height depends on the content's height. I have to either show the red view or the blue view depending on an if condition. So when the red view is shown, scroll view's height should be upto red view and when blue view is shown, red view's height should be set to 0.

I cannot set the height constraint of red and blue views as their height is the sum of the heights of its components, which is calculated automatically (also, it varies based on data coming from API).

I do not want to use container view. Can this be done purely through constraints?

[image]

EDIT: I want the constraints to be something that supports this, where I can just replace red view with blue view:

[image]

Comment: `I cannot set the height constraint ` Yes you can, just do it, or set its priority when you need it

Comment: @Lu_ how is that possible? please elaborate

Comment: Just set 0 height to blue and red box and in code change this constraints priority

Comment: IMO, the most appropriate thing here is to use UIStackView

Comment: @Lu_ everything turns red on storyboard when I set height to 0 of both UIView's

Comment: Do both of this boxes have `clipToBounds = true` ?

Comment: @Lu_I have given leading, trailing, top, bottom constraints to each component inside the UIView

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can give fix height in storyboard for all three UI controls. And change is dynamically in code later on. As per your requirement. 
Select the height constraint from the Interface builder and take an outlet of it. So, when you want to change the height of the view you can use the below code.

```
UIObjectHeightConstriant.constant = Height //(any value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use frameset for ScrollView it's perfectly working for you.

[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEFbb.png)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
   @IBOutlet weak var ScrollView : UIScrollView!
   @IBOutlet weak var ViewRED : UIView!
   @IBOutlet weak var ViewBLUE : UIView!

  @IBOutlet weak var ContentView : UIView!

 override func viewDidLoad()
 {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   self.ScrollView.frame = CGRect(x: ContentView.frame.origin.x, y: 
   ContentView.frame.origin.y, width: self.ContentView.frame.size.width, 
   height:self.ContentView.frame.size.height)

   frameset()

 }

  func frameSet()
  {
   if view == ViewRED // Here just mention condition for example you can set your condition
   {
      self.ScrollView.frame = CGRect(x: ViewRED.frame.origin.x, y: 
      ViewRED.frame.origin.y, width: self.ViewRED.frame.size.width, 
      height: self.ViewRED.frame.size.height)
   }

   if view == ViewBLUE//Here just mention condition for example you can set your condition
  {
     ViewRED.isHidden = true

     self.ScrollView.frame = CGRect(x: ViewBLUE.frame.origin.x, y: 
     ViewRED.frame.origin.y, width: self.ViewBLUE.frame.size.width, 
     height: self.ViewBLUE.frame.size.height)
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: scrollview height has to sum of upper view + red or blue view

Comment: yes, you can take ContentView Size until Blueview .

Comment: i mean ContentView height

Comment: ScrollView height not a problem what you take in Storyboard.Based on ContentView height we can set it.

Comment: `isHidden` does not solve my purpose. I need unused view's height to become 0

Comment: then set like this, self.ViewRED.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

Comment: can you share your code it's better to solve your problem easily?

Comment: There is no code. I need to do it through storyboard constraints

Comment: you can follow these steps  . first take a Scrollview then put ContentView Inside the scrollView.after that make sure your ContentView height must be sum of UpperView+viewRed+viewBlue

Comment: inside ContentView you have to put your UpperView,ViewBlue,ViewRed

Comment: first remove your all contraints , later you can set it and use above code it's working for you.

Comment: Your image shows red and blue views one below the other. I am looking for a solution that either shows red or blue views of varying height

Comment: through my code you can set it either red or blue views